# How to use SQL statement within NLog layout?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I know the following code doesn't work, but this is what I'm trying to do:

```
 <parameter name="@logtype_id" layout="select id from dbo.tracelog where lookup_category = 'Tracelog' and description = '${level}'" />
```

The SQL statement doesn't work like that inside layout="", but I want to return the value of `id` from that statement to the `@logtype_id` parameter depending on what the value of `${level}` layout is. The rest of the relevant code looks like this:

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
        dbUserName="internwebuser"
        dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionStringName="SECURE"
        connectionString="Data Source=abc.com;Initial Catalog=Db;User ID=userId;Password=password"
        commandText="insert into dbo.tracelog (user_id, logtype_id, page_name, custom_message, excep_message, insertdate) 
        values 
        (@user_id, @logtype_id, @page_name, @custom_message, @excep_message, @insertdate);" >



  <parameter name="@user_id"            layout="" />
  <parameter name="@logtype_id"         layout="select id from dbo.tracelog where lookup_category = 'Tracelog' and description = '${level}'" />
  <parameter name="@page_name"          layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=Url}" />
  <parameter name="@custom_message"     layout="${exception}" />
  <parameter name="@excep_message"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  <parameter name="@insertdate"         layout="${date}" />


</target>
```

Comment: You'd probably find it easier to use a custom target instead - http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html

Comment: @Lloyd Thanks! But is shows nothing about using SQL statement, do I use it just like in any other c# class?

Comment: This has been solved with a custom layout renderer, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1280

Comment: @Julian I posted that issue :D Anyways, thanks!